# how can I hide all the controls from facebook embedded video

Tags: facebook, video

I am trying to embed facebook video into my website. I saw facebook embedded video api to control (play, stop, etc) the video using javascript. I think there is someway to hide the default control element from facebook but I just don't know how to do it.

Facebook Embedded Video
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

I found this article:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/12/14/embedded-video-api-oembed

So, does it means I can only customise the default facebook video player by using uStudio?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to hide controls.

You can hide controls using `data-controls="false"`.

This option is not in documentation so I do no know if they will support it in the future.

Example code:

```
<div class="fb-video" data-href="<fb_video_url>" data-controls="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed in general:

> Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins (13.4)

If you want to change it, you don't need to use uStudio - just use the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api