# Remove All User Controls Facebook Video Embed

Tags: javascript, facebook, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm aware [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548820/how-can-i-hide-all-the-controls-from-facebook-embedded-video) exists, please don't mark this one as a duplicate as things have changed since it was originally posted.

I am looking to embed what's called a "secret" (aka private) Facebook video onto a sales page to serve as a video sales letter. The video needs to play automatically (for as many devices as possible, anyways) and needs to have all video control options removed.

Basically it's click to play, click to pause, and if they know to use the arrows to FF or rewind, then, so be it. But that'll be less than 1% I'm assuming.

In the old solution the person mentioned Facebook having the option `data-controls="false"`.

When trying to use this parameter now the entire video locks up and suggests the user to reload the browser.

Is there a way I can get around this? I'm thinking building out a custom player and seeing if I can set the FB video as the source, but even then it seems like there will be a page name and share option overlay on the video.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the video is not public, then you can not embed it at all via the Facebook video plugin. At most you could try and get the source URL from the API then, and create the player around it yourself. But those CDN URLs expire, you would likely have to refresh it regularly. And you will only get one video with a given bitrate, so any dynamic adjustment the original player might make in those regards, are also out of the window.

Comment: @04FS I was able to embed the video using the video plugin even though it was set to secret. I've been playing with it and I think the best solution would be to just block out the controls totally with a clear box with border that floats overtop the video. It's not pretty, but it works.