# Hide share btn on Facebook embedded video?

Tags: facebook, embedded-video

I am using iframe to embeded a video on my WordPress website.
But I would like to hide the Share buton on top-right corner, but not the other controls.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?height=476&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmyfacebook%2Fvideos%2FXX%2F&show_text=false&width=267&t=0" width="267" height="476" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is not possible, Facebook does not provide an option for that.

Comment: This question is already asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548820/how-can-i-hide-all-the-controls-from-facebook-embedded-video

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I hide all the controls from facebook embedded video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548820/how-can-i-hide-all-the-controls-from-facebook-embedded-video)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just want to hid ethe Share button but not other controls... Anyway if Facebook has no option for that...